# Woocommerce - custom post type of checkout page

Tags: posts, pages, woocommerce-offtopic, post-type

Is it possible to set custom post type page as a checkout page in woocommerce?
I can set only default pages, but I need different post type.

Comment: It's possible but why use a custom post type when you can just you a page and then restyle it to your heart's content?

Answer (score 0):

you have the answear right here:
[WooCommerce doc](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

> Example: To override the admin order notification, copy: wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php to wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php

Answer (score -1):

You can physically place the checkout shortcode on any page and it should load properly.

```
[woocommerce_checkout]
```

You will then probably want the WooCommerce buttons to link to the correct page from the cart page etc. There is a hook to enable this - put the below snippet in your theme functions.php file and use the post id of the custom checkout page. For this example my custom checkout has a post id of 62:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_url', function($url) {
    return get_permalink(62);
});
```

Comment: any reason for the downvote? if there is something wrong with my answer I would like to correct it.